# Как дать пользователю выбрать дату?

Tags: jquery

Необходимо, используя библиотеку jquery, обеспечить пользователю возможность указать дату своего рождения (компонент datetimepicker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это, конечно, здорово. Я еще понимаю с виртуалкой мучаться, но по пикеру есть офегительная дока.

Например: [jQuery Datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html).

Я считаю, что необходимо сначала самому хотя бы немного пошевелить головой.